# Redondear un jPanel en netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, material-design

He estado intentando con distintas soluciones que hay por internet y ninguna me funciona, no se si hay una manera sencilla de hacerlo y que no he intentado, aclaro la versión del NetBeans por si pueden haber inconvenientes, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: No se ve tu codigo, pero supongo quede ser igualito al de https://github.com/atarw/material-ui-swing

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Solo quería saber como se hacia para redondear un jPanel que tenia dentro de un jFrame ya que por si solo no se puede redondear pero ya ayer encontré la solución después de buscar y buscar, solo agregue una clase con un método que recibía el radio y el color y luego en Customize code del panel cree un nuevo objeto y puse el radio que quería y color y listo, Gracias :)